# windows xp - how to add a ipp printer by batch/vbs

Tags: windows-xp, printing, batch, vbscript

I need to deploy printers using IPP in the logon script (batch/vbs).

I found the following script to do this:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /q /b "r011-printer01 " /f %windir%\inf\ntprint.inf /r "http://10.0.0.1:631/printers/r011-printer01" /m "Apple Color Laserwriter 12/600"
```

This does seem to add the printer fine. However, when accessing the printer a "access denied" error occurs. The user adding the printers is an administrator account.

Adding the printer manually works fine, however I am required to enter Login-Credentials of a Local user. (?)

Comment: Please comment what's wrong if down-voting...

Comment: While I did not down vote you, I suspect it's because this information can be obtained easily with a google search. When asking questions we expect that you've at least done *some* research into your problem instead of simply asking how to do it. We'll help you resolve problems, but won't do your research for you.

Comment: The downvotes are most likely for what downvoting is used for.  "This question does not show any research effort".  You need to post things you've already tried or researched, why they didn't work, what methods you plan to use, etc.  SF doesn't really do "tell me how to do this so I don't have to figure it out at all".  Consider posting a script you can't get working, etc.

Comment: I revised the question to include what I have already tried + cups logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that a proxy was in use and even though it was checked in the proxy settings, local adresses did not bypass the proxy. 
By adding `10.*.*.*` to the proxy exceptions I got this fixed.

I didn't expect a printer to use the proxy at all anyway, though.

Edit: Apparantly adding a proxy exception does not work for the connections made while adding the printer - which results in a access denied exception when setting the printer as default before accessing the printer manually.